# Elasticsearch searching multi fields

Tags: elasticsearch, search, indexing, field

I would like to ask your help or any suggestions on my search requirements since I'm only new with elastisearch. This are my elastisearch index details:

```
_index               _type         _score     subs_name     subs_type
substation index     substation    1          Ad Diraz      loop 33
substation index     substation    1          Al Bareh      city 66 
substation index     substation    1          Budaiya       loop 33
substation index     substation    1          Galali        city 66
```

Now, I would like to search for any words between subs_name and sub_type:

1. If I search for **diraz loop** it would give me a search result of **Ad Diraz, loop 33**
2. If I search for **loop diraz** it would give me a search result of **Ad Diraz, loop 33**
3. If I search for **bareh 66** it would give me a search result of **Al Bareh, city 66**
4. If I search for **Galali** it would give me a search result of **Galali, city 66**
   and lastly
5. If I search for **Budaiya loop** it would give a search result of **Budaiya, loop 33**

I tried the elastisearch query below but it's only good for search no. 4

```
{"from": 0, "size": max_result,
    "query": {
    "multi_match": {
          "fields": ['subs_name', 'subs_type'],
          "query": search_this_query,
           "type": "phrase_prefix"
                   }
             }
}
```

Any help on what elasticsearch query to be used would be much appreciated. Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

If your two fields are of type string/text and use the same analyzer then you should use the cross_fields type for this query

```
GET /_search
{
  "query": {
    "multi_match" : {
      "query":      "diraz loop",
      "type":       "cross_fields",
      "fields":     [ "subs_name","subs_type"]
     "operator":   "and"
    }
  }
}
```